# What was the earliest use of the Rambam's language in Shmita V'Yovel in support of kollel study?

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, torah-study, rambam

Here's the Rambam, waxing poetic at the end of Laws of Shmita and Yovel (and his entire volume of Zeraim):

> ולא שבט לוי בלבד, אלא כל איש ואיש מכל באי העולם אשר נדבה רוחו אותו והבינו מדעו להיבדל לעמוד לפני ה' לשרתו ולעובדו לדעה את ה', והלך ישר כמו שעשהו האלוהים, ופרק מעל צווארו עול החשבונות הרבים אשר ביקשו בני האדם--הרי זה נתקדש קודש קודשים, ויהיה ה' חלקו ונחלתו לעולם ולעולמי עולמים; ויזכה לו בעולם הזה דבר המספיק לו, כמו שזיכה לכוהנים וללויים.  הרי דויד אומר "ה', מנת חלקי וכוסי--אתה, תומיך גורלי"
>
> Not only the Tribe of Levi, but each and every man from all those who traverse the earth, should their spirit move them and their intellect guide them to stand apart, to stand before G-d, to serve Him and know Him, and act appropriately as G-d intended, and he removes from his neck the yoke of all the troubles the masses seek -- such a person is sanctified holy of holies, and G-d shall be his portion and inheritance forever and ever; and he shall merit in this world enough to sustain himself, just as was provided for the Priests and Levites.  As David said, 'G-d, You are my portion of inheritance and my goblet, my supporter and my lot.' "

Today you'll [often hear this](http://www.jpost.com/JewishWorld/Judaism/Article.aspx?id=193488) quoted [in support of large-scale kollel funding](http://www.ou.org/publications/ja/5763/5763winter/ITTAKESA.PDF), though [others question](http://www.traditiononline.org/news/article.cfm?id=100958) if that's [what Rambam meant](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/718602/Rabbi_Zevulun_Charlop/Can_a_Non_Jew_Become_a_Kohen_Gadol).

Does anyone know who first cited this Rambam in support of kollel?

Comment: It would be cool to see examples of both sides of the contemporary argument.

Comment: Isaac - see links.  I don't want this question to become a flamewar about who's right, just when this was first cited.

Comment: Shalom, Thanks for the links. I understand and agree with your aim for this question. I'm sure the answer would prove useful to people interested in the philosophy and sociology of the kollel movement. I just feel that if you're going to refer to people saying stuff to support the relevance of your question and provide context for it, you accomplish those aims more effectively if you cite examples of such sayings.

Comment: Makes sense.  That's why I'm including the links, but not their arguments (other than perhaps any bias implied by my translation).

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/693/759

Comment: The Rambam never meant it to be the "source" for kollel learning...Two things... 1) If you'll notice he ends up every sefer with some sort of divrei aggaddah and not a psak halacha, that's what this is... 2) It's in contradiction to what he writes in Hilchos Talmud Torah that one must work and support ones self...

Comment: @Yehoshua that's my read as well. I'm asking a history question: today every kollel cites this Rambam; when did that practice start?

Comment: Right, so I think the answer below answers that. Especially since the modern day kollel system is "new" and no one 200 years ago+ would have imagined a system like ours. The Rema in Shulchan Aruch really only speaks about a Rav or a great talmid chacham being supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rav Yosef Yozel Horwitz the Alter of Novahrdok (1847–1919) already cites it in his talks compiled in the Sefer Madreigas Ha'adam in [Darkei Habitachon (chapter 13 s.v Vezeh Lashon Harambam)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41717&st=&pgnum=187)

Comment: where in the sefer?

Comment: See edit above with added source

Comment: excellent! I dont know what the traditional Mi Yodeya norms state about incorporating your answer into mine. Would that be appropriate?

Comment: I would rather it remain mine..if I understand you correctly. But with attribution I think it would be OK

Comment: What I wanted to discuss was whether or not he thought that it referred specifically to Torah study or to spiritual pursuits in general, *including* Torah study.

Comment: @Mefaresh thank you! He uses it in support of the phrase "with zero *hishtadlut*". (Mind you, Rabbi Horwitz secluded himself for a lengthy period.)

Comment: BTW accoridng to HebreBooks he was born in 1850.

Comment: @mevaqesh he uses it to justify learning without any concern for monetary endeavors. Thus he is using it to support the idea of living a life devoted exclusively to spiritual pursuits

Comment: @Mefaresh I thought I remembered him discussing learning but when I looked again, I didnt see it. Is it on that page?

Answer (score 6):

Biur Halacha [(156:1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=74) connects it to Torah study in particular, although not for large-scale kollel.

Chazon Ish (Kovetz Igros Chazon Ish vol. 1, letter 86) also clearly connects the Rambam to Torah study and even larger scale kollelim.

see [here](http://www.academia.edu/5926763/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%98_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%9D) at length.